# char comparison wrong output and no comparison in C

Tags: c, string, char

C is not comparing characters. I have tried many times and always with problems here.

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){
    int palavra[16];
    int frase[201];
    gets(palavra);
    gets(frase);
    printf("%s\n",palavra);
    printf("%s\n",frase);
    int i;
    int palavrasNaFrase=0;
    int tamanhoPalavra=strlen(palavra);
    int tamanhoFrase=strlen(frase);
    printf("tamanho frase %d\n",tamanhoFrase);
    for(i=0; i<tamanhoFrase; i++){
        printf("i = %d\n",i);
        printf("caracter: %c\n",palavra[0]);
        printf("caracter: %c\n",frase[i]);
        if(frase[i] == palavra[0]){
            printf("C is not comparing characters\n");/*
            int j=i+1,k=1;
            int letrasIguais=1;
            int cont=1;
            while(cont<tamanhoPalavra){
                if(frase[j]==palavra[k]){
                    letrasIguais++;
                }
                j++;
                k++;
                cont++;
            }
            if(letrasIguais==tamanhoPalavra){
                palavrasNaFrase++;
            }*/
        }
    }
    //printf("%d\n",palavrasNaFrase);
    return(0);
}
```

the input

```
ANA

ANAGOSTADEUMABANANA
```

the out

```
ANA

ANAGOSTADEUMABANANA

tamanho frase 19

i = 0

caracter: A

caracter: A

i = 1

caracter: A

caracter: O

i = 2

caracter: A

caracter: D

i = 3

caracter: A

caracter: A

i = 4

caracter: A

caracter: A

C is not comparing characters

i = 5

caracter: A

caracter: ©

i = 6

...

caracter: ­

0
```

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 4.696 s
Press any key to continue.

Is so bugged, that i dont know what to do.
Please someone help me, if someone can find what is the problem, why is so bugged. There is soooo many bugs and things happening that should not be happening. I have tried and search so many times and always i have found the way to compare strings char by char using string[position]==string2[position] was right but in this program is not working and i have no idea why so many bugs! Please someone help me and give me a light! What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Have you debugged it? We can't do the remote debugging for you. How do you know that *many bugs and things happening that should not be happening* when you clearly did not do any debugging?

Comment: don't use `gets()` function. It has been removed since C11 standard & before that it's use is deprecated.

Comment: I dont know how to debug

Comment: Have you read the problem at least before you coment? look at the output. Look at the input. There is something wrong. The output is showing characthers like  ¾, £,  ‼, ♀, that doesnt exists int the strings. And the printf is working well for the string, but not for each char separately. Read the problem and understand before judge

Comment: All I see is a code dump and you expect us to fix it for you?

Comment: You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-formatting). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/r/proper-c-obfuscation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're defining the arrays like this:

```
int palavra[16];
int frase[201];
```

while it reserves enough space, there's a problem when you're comparing char to char: you compare int to int (multi-char to multi-char) probably what you want here (and you probably had warnings about pointer types that you ignored):

```
if(frase[i] == palavra[0]){
```

You have to change your declarations to use `char` instead

```
char palavra[16];
char frase[201];
```

Compiling with warnings on you get this as expected. Fixing the warning would fix your code as well (extract of the warnings, redundant ones edited out):

```
$ gcc -Wall toto.c
toto.c: In function 'main':
toto.c:8:10: warning: passing argument 1 of 'gets' from incompatible pointer type
     gets(palavra);
          ^
In file included from toto.c:1:0:
c:\gnatpro\7.4.2\x86_64-pc-mingw32\include\stdio.h:491:17: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'int *'

          ^
In file included from toto.c:1:0:
c:\gnatpro\7.4.2\x86_64-pc-mingw32\include\stdio.h:491:17: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'int *'
   char *__cdecl gets(char *_Buffer) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
                 ^
     ^
toto.c:11:5: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int *'
 [-Wformat=]
     printf("%s\n",frase);
     ^
toto.c:14:31: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlen' from incompatible pointer type
     int tamanhoPalavra=strlen(palavra);
                               ^
```

Comment: You should also add that OP's code invokes UB due to incorrect format specifiers.

Comment: @Destructor: did even better: compiled with warnings on so all errors pop up.

Comment: @FernandoHenrique: don't be discouraged. But next time compile with warnings and read them, fix your code until there's none left.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for that. I will look for the warnings next time

Comment: you'll be surprised how many industrial products issue warnings when compiling. A lot of developpers blatantly ignore them, and hunt bugs for hours instead. Don't be like that :)